# Context.WithTimeout() and os.exit in gorilla/mux

Tags: go, server, gorilla, mux

I'm using the Golang gorilla/mux package, and one of the examples is as follows:

```
func main() {
    var wait time.Duration
    flag.DurationVar(&wait, "graceful-timeout", time.Second * 15, "the duration for which the server gracefully wait for existing connections to finish - e.g. 15s or 1m")
    flag.Parse()

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    // Add your routes as needed

    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:         "0.0.0.0:8080",
        // Good practice to set timeouts to avoid Slowloris attacks.
        WriteTimeout: time.Second * 15,
        ReadTimeout:  time.Second * 15,
        IdleTimeout:  time.Second * 60,
        Handler: r, // Pass our instance of gorilla/mux in.
    }

    // Run our server in a goroutine so that it doesn't block.
    go func() {
        if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }()

    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    // We'll accept graceful shutdowns when quit via SIGINT (Ctrl+C)
    // SIGKILL, SIGQUIT or SIGTERM (Ctrl+/) will not be caught.
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)

    // Block until we receive our signal.
    <-c

    // Create a deadline to wait for.
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), wait)
    defer cancel()
    // Doesn't block if no connections, but will otherwise wait
    // until the timeout deadline.
    srv.Shutdown(ctx)
    // Optionally, you could run srv.Shutdown in a goroutine and block on
    // <-ctx.Done() if your application should wait for other services
    // to finalize based on context cancellation.
    log.Println("shutting down")
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

This seems simple enough, but my understanding is that defers do not run when `os.Exit()` is called (as per https://gobyexample.com/exit). I notice that there's a `CancelFunc()` returned by `context.WithTimeout()`, which is then deferred. My guess is that this is supposed to cancel the context created above if `main()` finishes before the deadline, but I don't see how that can happen with a call to `os.Exit()` at the end. Could anyone help me see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You right, the deferred cancel function is never called. The author want probably point out that in real application, you should never forget to cancel your context.